# Call Javascript Function from MVC view in loading page without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ho I can Call Javascript/TypeScipt Funtion when the MVC View Loads. without using Jquery. This is my function:

```
function BuildGrid() {

let header = '[{"data": [{"id": "Id","name": "Full Name","age": "Age"}]}]';
let myheader = JSON.parse(header);

.......
```

and I was calling it in html page like:

```
 <body onload="BuildGrid();">
```

.... To show the grid, But how I now I want to have this code in MVC view that there is no body. How I can call it?

Comment: The body is likely in the _Layout page. Is this a partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping in window.onload

Here is an example

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // x functionality when window loads

  alert('hello');
  
  
}
```